# use HTTPS to browse locally used site

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, iis-7

I have a website used locally in my domain using IIS7 installed on Windows 2008. This website is bound to HTTP, and I need to bind it using HTTPS.

I searched around and I saw that it's possible with the following solution (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Install an Enterprise CA and use it to issue a certificate that can be used on IIS.
- Then add an HTTPS binding to the website using this certificate.

If the above is possible is there any website that describes what needs to be done in details?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's how to create a self-signed cert in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?ppud=4), and [here's how to bind it to the site](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx). As mentioned in the second link, your users will see a certificate error when accessing the site; the way to get around this is to buy a real cert from your CA of choice, and bind that to the website instead.

Comment: Hi Aaron, is the only way to use HTTPS in my enviroment is to use a self-signed cert? Is it possible to configure a CA and use it internally?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the sense of your question initially. I haven't used a local CA myself, but [this](http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/04/16/install-an-enterprise-certificate-authority-in-windows-2008-r2/) might help.

Comment: Hi Aaron. I don't want to use self-signed certificate. i prefer to use CA. is it possible to have a CA?